# Access modelData within delegate in QML

Tags: qt, view, model, qml, repeater

Is there a way to access `modelData` from View delegate (Repeater in particular).

I tried to use a separate property and tried to access it via `model.modelData` but neither of this worked.

Please see code snapshot below.

Thanks in advance.

```
Component
{
    id: comp_1
    Rectangle
    {
        color: "green"
        width: 200
        height: 200
    }
}

Component
{
    id: comp_2
    Rectangle
    {
        color: "red"
        width: 200
        height: 200

        Text
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            text: modelData
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }
    }
}

function getDelegate(itemName)
{
    if(itemName === "comp1")
        return comp_1;
    else
        return comp_2;
}

Row
{
    Repeater
    {
        id: repeat
        model: ["comp1", "comp2"]
        Loader
        {
            sourceComponent: getDelegate(modelData)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#accessing-views-and-models-from-delegates) page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add a property on the delegate element

```
Component {
    id: comp_1
    Rectangle {
        property string valueFromModel
    }
}
```

and bind the modelData to it

```
Loader {
    id: loader
    Binding {
        target: loader.item
        property: "valueFromModel"
        value: model.modelData
    }
}
```